# Laravel query return an Invalid parameter number error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass some parameter to my query but I get this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select username, groupname from `radusergroup` where username like '00:00:00:00:00:00%') in file /home/gwendal/Documents/radius/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 742
```

My query look like this :

```php
$user = DB::connection('freeradius')
        ->table('radusergroup')
        ->selectRaw('username, groupname')
        ->whereRaw("username like '?%'", [$mac])
        ->get();
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you are using query builder instead of eloquent? Do you have any specific requirements to do so?

Comment: I'm connecting to databases that werent created with Laravel so I cant use eloquent.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a way to make my raw query.
I was trying to put the value of the $whereStatement variable directly in the whereRaw and this kept on giving me an error.
Putting the statement in a variable worked.

```php
$whereStatement = "username like '". $mac ."%'";

$user = DB::connection('freeradius')
  ->table('radusergroup')
  ->whereRaw($whereStatement)
  ->selectRaw('username, groupname')
  ->get();
```

Hope this help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: This is something you should not do. This is insecure code because you are not using bindings.